# Agile Process Unable to move User Stories in Sprint pane

Tags: azure-devops

My issue: When I go to Sprint and in the first column, I see my user stories. I want to move them into the columns that I created like Backlog and Ready for sprint Active and so on. but when I go to drag them they will not stay. (I read that only task and bugs can move, on another question, ok get it)
so how can you get accurate sprint burn down charts and cumulative flow and understand the velocity when the User stories won't move? They move under boards view. This is not syncing with the charts. What could be the possible solution? Thank you

I was expecting to move the user stories and tasks and bugs to the next columns during sprint planning.
I was expecting the team to see their progress from the analytics view.

Comment: Please tell us what exactly is not working, not why you want to do it. This may also be a case where a picture would actually help

Answer (score -1):

When you move the user story to different column under the boards view, the user story state will be changed, the **Cumulative Flow Diagram** and **velocity** are changed as well since it monitors on work item states by default. It's same for the **sprint burn down charts** in Sprints view. Please refer to the docs below to understand how they are defined. Please note the different state scope(active, closed..etc) they are monitoring.

[View and configure a Cumulative Flow Diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow?view=azure-devops)

[View and configure team velocity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops&tabs=in-context)

[Configure and monitor sprint burndown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay)

> I was expecting to move the user stories and tasks and bugs to the next columns during sprint planning. I was expecting the team to see their progress from the analytics view.

The analytics view has a time scope, if you move the user stories, tasks, bugs to the next column/iteration during sprint planning, make sure you the time scope is correct. You can also created self-defined widgets or charts mentioned in doc above if you don't want to use in-context type.